# Dispatcher, BackgroundWorker or Parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest

As part of trying to learn C#, I'm writing a small app that goes through a list of proxies. For each proxy it will create an httpwebrequest to a proxytest.php which prints generic data about a given proxy (or doesn't, in which case the proxy is discarded)

Clearly the webrequest code needs to run in a separate thread - especially since I'm planning on going through rather large lists. But even on a separate thread, going through 5,000 proxies will take forever, so I think this means I am to create multiple threads (correct me if I'm wrong)

I looked through MSDN and random threading tutorials and there's several different classes available. What's the difference between dispatcher, backgroundworker and parallel? I was given this snippet:

```
Parallel.ForEach(URLsList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = S0 }, (m, i, j) =>
  {
    string[] UP = m.Split('|');
    string User = UP[0];
    string Pass = UP[1];
 // make call here
 }
```

I'm not really sure how it's different than something like starting 5 separate background workers would do.

So what are the differences between those three and what would be a good (easy) approach to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is an object that models the message loop of WPF applications. If that doesn't mean anything to you then forget you ever heard of it.

[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is a convenience class over a thread that is part of the [managed thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx). It exists to provide some commonly requested functionality over manually assigning work to the thread pool with [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2b9a8h2.aspx).

The [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class is very much like using the managed thread pool, with the difference being that you are in absolute control of the thread's lifetime (on the flip side, it's worse than using the thread pool if you intend to launch lots of short tasks).

The [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (TPL) (i.e. using `Parallel.ForEach`) would indeed be the best approach, since it not only takes care of assigning work units to a number of threads (from the managed thread pool) but it will also automatically divide the work units among those threads.

Comment: So for the example snippet in the OP, will the Parallel.ForEach create a thread for each of the entries in the URLsList? won't that be kind of a problem?

Comment: @Vlad: No, because a) it uses the managed thread pool (so typically no threads are created; sleeping threads are just woken up) and b) it only uses up to a specified number of threads (`MaxDegreeOfParalellism = ... `).

Comment: TPL is not guaranteed to always increase performance and not always the best approach, there are numerous scenarios where TPL may hurt performance, it is highly recommended to profile and see if TPL actually helps.

Comment: @RohitSharma: Noone mentioned performance here, so I don't see how your comment is relevant. But anyway it will *certainly* have better performance vs any solution that does not use the thread pool, assuming there is no other pressure on the thread pool at the same time.

Comment: Well the reason we use thread is for performance isn't it?. Try this program with and with out TPL - find the sum of 1 to 100, if you use TPL to divide and sum, you'd see you are decreasing performance when using TPL. If some one is studying threading, i would encourage them to know these fine points. See Overexposing parallelism http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx

Comment: @Jon, i did, didn't mean to nitpick, I just wanted to highlight the fact that vlad is learning threading in c# - the example is just his test, from  your answer he may actually end up applying the same approach for other cases, so pointing out the gottcha at this stage is better for him.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use the task parallel library. It is a new library around all the manual threading code you will have to write otherwise.

> The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is a collection of new classes specifically designed to make it easier and more efficient to execute very fine-grained parallel workloads on modern hardware. TPL has been available separately as a CTP for some time now, and was included in the Visual Studio 2010 CTP, but in those releases it was built on its own dedicated work scheduler. For Beta 1 of CLR 4.0, the default scheduler for TPL will be the CLR thread pool, which allows TPL-style workloads to “play nice” with existing, QUWI-based code, and allows us to reuse much of the underlying technology in the thread pool - in particular, the thread-injection algorithm, which we will discuss in a future post.

from

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2009/04/23/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1.aspx

I found working with this new 4 library really easy. This blog is showing the old BackgroundWorker way of doing things and the new Task way of doing things.

http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html

Comment: And look at this one, more summarized: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html